jQuery multiselect.js selects all options even they are not visible

I use this plugin to make multiselect more comfortable - http://loudev.com/.
I have also integrated search via quicksearch plugin.
And I have set optgroup can be selected

But I would need, if any query is searched and optgroup is selected, to select only options which were found. If item is not match searched query, it is hidden via style="display: none", so I thought best practice to filter them out is to use :visible selector, but it does not work. I've also tried :not(:hidden), but it does not work either.
This is the code, which selects all options when optgroup is clicked.
$selectableOptgroup.find('.ms-optgroup-label').on('click', function(){
  var values = $optgroup.children(':not(:selected, :disabled)').map(function(){ return $(this).val();}).get();
  that.select(values);
});

And I've tried to edit this way, but still all options are selected.
$selectableOptgroup.find('.ms-optgroup-label').on('click', function(){
  var values = $optgroup.children(':not(:selected, :disabled, :hidden)').map(function(){ return $(this).val();}).get();
  that.select(values);
});

This is HTML which I got when I call init function of multiselect plugin.
<div class="ms-container" id="ms-email_contacts">
  <div class="ms-selectable"><input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="... vyhledávání ...">
    <ul class="ms-list" tabindex="-1">
      <li class="ms-optgroup-container" id="optgroup-selectable--1866734926">
        <ul class="ms-optgroup">
          <li class="ms-optgroup-label" style=""><span>group 1</span></li>
          <li class="ms-elem-selectable" id="1698467390-selectable" style=""><span>a@a.cz (pr-1)</span></li>
          <li class="ms-elem-selectable" id="-181089201-selectable" style=""><span>test@test.cz</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="ms-optgroup-container" id="optgroup-selectable--1867902347">
        <ul class="ms-optgroup">
          <li class="ms-optgroup-label" style=""><span>Group 2</span></li>
          <li class="ms-elem-selectable" id="-29257990-selectable" style=""><span>a@a.cz (pr-1)</span></li>
          <li class="ms-elem-selectable" id="289161371-selectable" style=""><span>test@test.cz</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="ms-selection"><input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="... vyhledávání ...">
    <ul class="ms-list" tabindex="-1">
      <li class="ms-optgroup-container" id="optgroup-selection--1866734926">
        <ul class="ms-optgroup">
          <li class="ms-optgroup-label" style="display: none;"><span>group 1</span></li>
          <li class="ms-elem-selection" id="1698467390-selection" style="display: none;"><span>a@a.cz (pr-1)</span></li>
          <li class="ms-elem-selection" id="-181089201-selection" style="display: none;"><span>test@test.cz</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="ms-optgroup-container" id="optgroup-selection--1867902347">
        <ul class="ms-optgroup">
          <li class="ms-optgroup-label" style="display: none;"><span>Group 2</span></li>
          <li class="ms-elem-selection" id="-29257990-selection" style="display: none;"><span>a@a.cz (pr-1)</span></li>
          <li class="ms-elem-selection" id="289161371-selection" style="display: none;"><span>test@test.cz</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

And I init it by this function:
  function selectMulti(id, search_msg) {
    $('#' + id).multiSelect({
      selectableOptgroup: true,
      keepOrder: true,
      selectableHeader: '<input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="' + search_msg + '">',
      selectionHeader: '<input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="' + search_msg + '">',
      afterInit: function(ms) {
        var that = this,
            $selectableSearch = that.$selectableUl.prev(),
            $selectionSearch = that.$selectionUl.prev(),
            selectableSearchString = '#'+that.$container.attr('id')+' li.ms-elem-selectable:not(.ms-selected)',
            selectionSearchString = '#'+that.$container.attr('id')+' li.ms-elem-selection.ms-selected';
        that.qs1 = $selectableSearch.quicksearch(selectableSearchString)
        .on('keydown', function(e){
          if (e.which === 40){
            that.$selectableUl.focus();
            return false;
          }
        });
        that.qs2 = $selectionSearch.quicksearch(selectionSearchString)
        .on('keydown', function(e){
          if (e.which == 40){
            that.$selectionUl.focus();
            return false;
          }
        });
      },
      afterSelect: function() {
        this.qs1.cache();
        this.qs2.cache();
      },
      afterDeselect: function() {
        this.qs1.cache();
        this.qs2.cache();
      }
    });
  }


Please edit your question and also provide an example of the HTML for the elements this JavaScript / jQuery operates on. It would be helpful if that example also includes at least one "hidden" option so we can reproduce the problem you described.

Sure, sorry about that, I've edited my origional post.
